# How to set page header cf-cache-status: HIT?

Tags: caching, header, cloudflare, cache-control

I have set the page header to the public by htaccess file.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

But still, it is showing `cf-cache-status:` as `DYNAMIC` for the static HTML page too. Please let me know if there is an additional setting at Cloudflare or the website header.

Comment: I would reach out to cloudflare support. This isn't a PHP question.. looks like code is htaccess or httpd.conf for apache.

Comment: Yes, This code is from htaccess file. I just want to confirm if it is not related to the coding side issue.
If it is related to Cloudflare, what are the settings?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to review the [Default Cache Behaviour](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior) documentation page which explains how the Cloudflare Cache works and how to configure it to cache (or bypass caching) different resources. To summarise:

- By default only specific file extensions are cached
- You can set specific Page Rules to override the default behaviour
- You can also use Cloudflare Workers to achieve a customized caching result
- You can also use [Cache-Control](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/cache-control) headers, as long as the resource is deemed cacheable (see above)